# rails - a slug not updated after changed the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

I have a model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
    validates :slug, :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
    before_validation :generate_slug

    def to_param
        slug
    end

    def generate_slug
        name_as_slug = Russian.translit(name).parameterize
        if parent.present?
          self.slug = [parent.slug, (slug.blank? ? name_as_slug : slug.split('/').last)].join('/')
        else
          self.slug = name_as_slug if slug.blank?
        end
    end
end
```

My problem is that I can't update the slug after changed field **"Name"** of the record. For instance, if the slug was `/page-1/page-1-1/page-1-1-1` for the Page with `name: **"Page 1.1"**` that after the change of name to `Page Abrakadabra` slug remains the same instead of `/page-1/page-1-1/page-abrakadabra`.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The ternary operator there preserves your existing slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your use of `slug.blank?` is preventing the change.

How about something like this instead?

```
def generate_slug
  name_as_slug = Russian.translit(name).parameterize
  return if name_as_slug == slug.split('/').last
  slug_elements = []
  slug_elements << parent.slug if parent.present?
  slug_elements << name_as_slug
  self.slug = slug_elements.join('/')
end
```